# Cocos2d: Setting zOrder at run time for CCSprite batched in sprite nodes doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, particle-system

I was able to call those methods at run time on a CCSprite object, now that I decided to batch it in a CCSpriteBatchNode it doesn't seem to work anymore:

```
sprt = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sprt.png"];
sprt.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
sprt.position = CGPointMake(40.0f, 60.0f);
[batchNode addChild:sprt z:-1];  // It used to work when I was simply "adding as child" the sprt object, I guess now doesn't set the order anymore because somehow the CCSpriteBatch node doesn't allow the re-ordering of child added to it

CCCallFunc *callback = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveBackwards)];
CCCallFunc *callback2 = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveForward)];

[sprt runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCSequence actions:  callback2,  callback ,  nil]]];

-(void) moveBackwards
{
    [sprt setZOrder:-1];
 }

-(void) moveForward
{
    [sprt setZOrder:1];
}
```

Comment: does it "not work" relatively to other sprites in this batch node or relatively to objects not in this batch node?

Comment: to the ones in the same batch node

Answer (score 2):

If you have a CCSpriteBatchNode, you have to consider all the CCSprite to be on the same layer (the spritebatch node).

This means that sprites in a sprite batch node can change their z order relative to other sprites in the sprite batch node, but you can not change the z order to make a sprite-batched sprite appear behind or in front of another node that is not a child of the sprite's CCSpriteBatchNode.

I'm pretty sure this is the problem you've run into. If you have trouble grasping this, consider the CCSpriteBatchNode has the same behavior regarding z ordering as a CCLayer (respectively any other node but devs seem to be hung up on CCLayer as the only/main layering construct). Maybe that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, I do appreciate the answer and I understand. CCSpriteBatchNode is considered as a layer and childs of a batch node can only change in respect to its layer (you had given me this answer some months ago already). Unfortunately, as far as I understand, that's not the problem I am facing. My problem is to change the order at RUN TIME and it doesn't seem to work. I have an object which I am moving forwards and backwards dynamically and it would only remember the first z-Order that I gave using CCSpriteBatchNodes.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else runs across this issue, the following will work to reorder the sprite...

[self.parent reorderChild:self z:x];